# How to save the number of registered users in mongodb?

Tags: python, html, django, mongodb

I have a problem and I am looking for a solution. I want to save the number of users registered in mongodb. For example, in django, the admin page has the number of registered users, and all other data is saved there. I want it to be saved in mongodb database instead of showing it on admin page, because my other data is also saved in mongodb. How do I do this? Should I make separate a class in `models.py` or something else.

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow, Can you provide [minimal reproducible example!](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) Please go through the [tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour), the help center and the [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask) sections to see how this site works and to help you improve your current and future questions, which can help you get better answers. Please also have a look at [How do I ask](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10812/162852).

Comment: The number of users is `User.objects.count()` maybe with a filter to count only active users. Never save data that can be calculated/derived from other data, as this will just lead to inconsistencies. Why do you want to save it? You'd have to make sure the number is updated every time a new user is added/deleted and it's so easy to forget places in your code where this might happen.

Answer (score 1):

You are asking a wrong question, because you should not do that.

The number of users is `User.objects.count()` maybe with a filter to count only active users.

Never save data that can be calculated/derived from other data, as this will just lead to inconsistencies. Why do you want to save it? You'd have to make sure the number is updated every time a new user is added/deleted and it's so easy to forget places in your code where this might happen.